# ngIf with as as syntax and && operator

Tags: angular

How can I combine the ngIf as syntax with a && operator? The following code results in an "Expected identifier or keyword" error

```
 <control-error *ngIf="(createUserError | async as userError) && submitted">
          {{userError}}
 </control-error>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as` syntax is applied only to the whole `*ngIf` expression.

So, this is the valid syntax:

```
*ngIf="(createUserError | async) && submitted as userError"
```

which will either hide that block or render `true`.

But in order to make it right and logicaly correct you can change the order:

```
*ngIf="submitted && (createUserError | async) as userError"
```

which should result in the right value for `userError` variable.